# England +do / does

Tags: grammar, singular-vs-plural

Is *England* (or any other country) singular or plural?

Should I say `England don't want to...` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Country names are singular since they are collective nouns

> England **is**
>   England **doesn't** want to...
>
> The United States of America is...
>   Canada is...
>   Germany is...

However you may hear

> The Philippines are a group of islands.
>   The United Arab Emirates are a a federation of seven emirates.

which is understandable but grammatically incorrect.

Comment: I have heard the United States used as a plural.  After all, it is supposed to be a union of states, not a country.

Comment: "These united states are..." is not the same as "The United States is..."

Comment: *Before the Civil War, the states were all separate. People used to say "The United States are." Wasn't until the war ended, people started saying "The United States is." Under Lincoln, we became one nation.* [- National Treasure](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0465234/quotes?item=qt0475017)